# What is the average value of a credit card or debit card transaction?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, debit-card, transaction, statistics

There are a plethora of statistics regarding credit card usage but what I can't seem to find is the the value of the average credit card (or debit card) transaction.

Are such statistics provided by payment processing companies or is this information typically not given? Does anyone know any sources for this information?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: **plethora of statistics**. And what purpose does it serve anybody to collate all of them ? Government will probably do for its own citizens, card companies will do for their own customers, credit rating agencies will probably do for the country they are located in. So it maybe difficult to do it for all transactions, maybe you have to do it yourself.

Comment: I am asking this in "personal finance" because the question relates to personal financial topics.  (If there is a better site for this question, I apologize for not asking it there.)  Anyway, I have a project that I'm working on and this metric would be quite useful.  What I've found is that many of the credit card companies to offer general statistics about their average, household client (i.e. How much debt they own, debt-to-income ratio, etc.) but I couldn't find a metric, any where, stating the size of the average transaction.  It would be an interesting figure to know, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Credit Cards

There are quite a few statistics on this subject.

[indexcreditcards.com](http://www.indexcreditcards.com/finance/creditcardstatistics/2011-report-on-credit-card-usage-facts-statistics.html) - This might be a good starting point.

> The Federal Reserve reports that credit cards are used more than 20 billion times a year in the U.S., with the total value of these transactions at about $1.9 trillion.
>
> Based on the number of transactions and the number of credit card holders, the average card holder uses a credit card 119 times a year, for transactions averaging $88 apiece. This comes to an average annual total of about $10,500 in credit card purchases.

[PFblog](http://www.pfblog.com/archives/1318_average_size_of_credit_card_transaction.shtml)

> CardWeb reported that in the last year, the average size of credit card transaction tops $100 for the first time. 2003's average of $101.64 is 1.9% higher than last year's $99.76 and represents 16% increase in 10 years.

[Quora](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-average-size-of-a-US-consumers-credit-card-purchases)

> At the end of 2009 the average purchase made with Visa or MasterCard Credit Cards was $82.56, a number lower than previous years, where the average was slightly over $100. You can order more recent reports on this figure from CardData.

The indexcreditcards.com article might have some useful strategies for calculating these statistics, like combining the Federal Reserve data (for example, from [FRED](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/tags/series/?t=credit+cards)) with Census and industry estimates. That's probably the best place to start for recent data that shouldn't cost anything (or if it does, the cost shouldn't be prohibitive). [Cardweb](http://cardweb.com/publications/carddata/) looks like it compiles the information you need too, but according to their site, subscriptions start at $1,495.00.

If you need this data for research purposes, citing a website isn't sufficient, but assuming you describe how to came up with your statistics, combining data sets in the way mentioned above should work.

#### Debit Cards

For similar information relating to debit cards, the [Federal Reserve](http://www.federalreserve.gov/paymentsystems/regii-average-interchange-fee.htm) also has information about that, since they work with payment processing networks.

> There were approximately 46.7 billion debit card transactions in 2011,
> with a value of more than $1.8 trillion. This was a 24 percent
> increase from the number of transactions in 2009 (37.6 billion) and a
> 27 percent increase from the value of transactions in 2009 ($1.4
> trillion). Signature debit transactions represented about 63 percent
> of transaction volume and 61 percent of transaction value in 2011; the
> remainder were PIN debit transactions.

mainstreet.com also cites [data provided by mint.com](http://www.mainstreet.com/article/moneyinvesting/credit/debt/how-americans-use-their-debit-cards?page=1) which finds that "the average debit card transaction amount in 2010 was $71." This isn't a random sample because it only represents data on mint.com users. Intuitively, I can think of reasons for why users of mint.com would spend either more or less than the population as a whole, but I'm not sure which is true.

Keep in mind, though, that debit card transactions [might qualify](http://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/press/bcreg/20130305a.htm) as Electronic Fund Transfers, which could complicate the picture. I haven't researched payment processing networks extensively, so I can't make a statement on that one way or another.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much.  All of this information is quite useful.

Comment: @RLH Glad to hear it. I added a link to [FRED](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/tags/series/?t=credit+cards) at the St. Louis Fed, which has a few time series that might be relevant.

Comment: Do you know if this also relates to Debit Card transactions?  I ask because my specific project needs to come up with a baseline, average value of the average consumer purchase, regardless of the type of purchase made.

Comment: @RLH See my edit. Once again, the Federal Reserve maintains some relevant data on the subject.

Comment: @RLH You might want to check out the [Consumer Expenditure Survey](http://www.bls.gov/cex/) as well, if you're interested in highly detailed data about consumer expenditures.

Comment: This is an absolutely terrific answer. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

I'm don't know what the extent of your project is, but there are studies that have shown people generally spend MORE when they use plastic - specifically cash vs. credit, not sure if the number is higher when it's cash vs. debit.  You may want to start there, and see what you find.  If that figure does not exist on its own, you may just have to use the averages you mentioned.  If it were my project, I would state that I couldn't find that number, but here are the averages from these different sources and possibly use an average of *those averages,* but I'm not entirely sure what that number would indicate.

1. Carnegie Melon: http://www.cmu.edu/homepage/practical/2007/winter/spending-til-it-hurts.shtml
2. MIT: http://web.mit.edu/simester/Public/Papers/Alwaysleavehome.pdf
3. NPR Interview Robert Frank (Cornell Econ. Prof.)
   http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=92178034

Comment: "there are studies" implies at least more than one. Can you cite one or two? It's a "well known fact" that people spend more on cards than with cash, and yet, I've not seen one study that wasn't contrived. e.g. an experiment in which college students are given a $10 gift card or $10 cash and walked into McDonalds. To anyone with a drop of statistician's blood running through their veins such studies are useless in that they do not extrapoloate to the multi-thousand dollar budget of adults.

Comment: Edited my answer with references.

Maybe I'm the only one in the whole US of A, but I certainly found it to be true in my personal life.

When I worked at Best Buy years ago, one of the things we were encouraged to offer were credit cards (either the store card or the RewardZone Mastercard) because...the average sales tickets were higher than other forms of payment (cash, check, or debit).  We were told that the credit cards gave the customer more "purchasing power."

Comment: forgive me, you get points for followup, but the references all prove my point. Small studies with low dollars at risk. The study of how a student decides how much to spend on one sporting ticket doesn't extrapolate to 'real life' in my opinion. I suspect the study I'd be looking for doesn't exist. It would be too expensive with no one to support it. Please understand, I'm not really disputing the fact itself, just that it remains unproven.

Comment: I still disagree with @JoeTaxpayer on the "small studies" point.  We will have to agree to disagree. However, McDonald's has said themselves that people spend more when using credit vs cash.  (McD's is cited in this article: http://www.investopedia.com/articles/pf/08/pay-in-cash.asp) John Bensin makes the point (spending more with credit vs cash) I was getting at with the studies all the same though.

Comment: @Waddler - The Investopedia article links to a SoundMoneyTips site that appears dead. It also cites a mythical D&B study that doesn't exist. http://www.getrichslowly.org/blog/2010/04/27/money-myths-and-the-importance-of-thinking-for-yourself/ mentions the lack of such an article. The internet is a funny place, a non-existent article is cited, and that citation is quoted over and over. While the premiss is quite believable, and the McDonald effect likely 100% true, you'd be hard pressed to pick through a $3K-$4K/month budget and find that kind of overspending.

Comment: Well done @JoeTaxpayer.  Bravo.  ::: claps, genuinely ::: 

As far as your budget point goes, my thought is if someone is only budgeting to pay the minimum on a credit card or cards, then you're right - you wouldn't find that kind of overspending on the budget.  People overspend (some times a little here and there - death by a thousand cuts) and then pay minimum payments on the credit card(s).  Are you assuming people who use credit are paying off the balance in full each month?

Comment: @waddler - (thank you) not at all. For discussion's sake, say only 20% pay in full. My claim is that these people are less prone to the effect of overspending on credit cards. I agree, there's a 'credit effect' but believe it's not easily quantifiable (no real study, yet) and that there are two 'populations' that need segregating within a thorough study.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, I found the article from Carnegie Mellon, it refrences *the* study.  (http://goo.gl/qOWIWJ)  It links to a summary of it as well (http://goo.gl/ex6aH5). And here's a link to where the study is published (Neuron, a science journal): http://goo.gl/Ap5UN5  Note, it's been cited 298 times.