# My spouse and I can make a budget, but how can I get her to consistently follow it?

Tags: budget, marriage

This question is similar to this question: [I can make a budget, but how can I get myself to consistently follow my budget?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5299/i-can-make-a-budget-but-how-can-i-get-myself-to-consistently-follow-my-budget/5301#5301) except from the point of view of a married couple.

In our family I earn the money and my wife spends it.  For various reason it isn't feasible for us both to work, nor is it feasible for me to be in charge of spending the money, aside from having already automated all the recurring expenses such as mortgage and utilities.   However, this still leaves the "general" category of everything else that doesn't fit, including things food, household goods and supplies, and fuel.

We both agree that we need a budget, and we have even sat down on multiple occasions and have agreed on a dollar amount for our general expenses.  We have various tools to try to keep under budget such as Mint and an expense tracker, but it never happens.  My wife admits that it is her fault, and that she is "bad at money" but I am struggling to find a solution that will both keep us solvent and keep her happy at the same time.

At first I thought maybe it was just poor planning: you have everything in mind you are going to get for the month, but then something unexpected comes up and it blows your budget.  But after reading some of the comments on my previous draft, I guess there is some game theory involved here.  If the budget isn't kept, then we both feel bad but at least she gets all the things she feels that the kids and us need.  Even though she feels bad and wants to do better, I feel like she wins and I lose, so there isn't sufficient incentive for her to really do better.

So my question is, how can I find a scenario in which, if she doesn't stick with the budget, she loses?

Also, regarding the comment by @Question3CPO to make it so that "neither you nor her have access to the money the plan says to save. In that case, neither of you can go over."  That sounds good, but how do you achieve this in practice?  I don't know of a practical way of making a hard limit on funds that doesn't either cause potential safety issues (what if you need funds in an emergency) or increase costs and inconvenience (e.g. can't buy things online).

edit: Ok, I cleaned up the question but apparently it was still closed anyway.  Not sure where to go from here...

Comment: Is this a blog post?

Comment: Frame your question more appropriately or else people would vote it to be closed.

Comment: You know what TLDR stands for? "too long, didn't read." Your question might have validity, but the title says much of it. You literally wrote 1026 words to ask a question. Take it down to 200-250 tops, and you'll get some good comments, I think.

Comment: Regardless of the spouse, as long as someone has nothing to lose (in this case, your wife), the person doesn't have to contribute and doesn't face repercussions if they don't contribute.  This is basic human nature (see Game Theory in economics).  You must find a scenario in which, if she doesn't get on board the plan, she loses.  Then you'll achieve a win-win.  Also, automate everything where neither you nor her have access to the money the plan says to save.  In that case, neither of you can go over.

Comment: @Question3CPO - Are you married? There's a saying "If you're not happy, but your wife is happy, you are still far happier than if you were happy but your wife's not happy." Your proposal is lose-lose.

Comment: @Andy - your question will be closed. It's worth the time to edit and it will be a candidate for reopening.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I am!

Comment: I can't believe I'm going to agree with JoeTaxpayer.  Andy, I see from your question that you are as happily married as me. ;)) I think Dave Ramsey's approach is the best available.  Listen to his radio show if it's still on.  Get her to listen after a while.  Work together.  In advanced lingo: view your household as a business.  Outline the amazing wealth you'll both have if you strip down and invest everything properly.  Sell her the dream of bigger houses, more to spend.

Comment: @Question3CPO I think you hit it on the head.  Should I  write a tl;dr at the beginning and leave the rest for reference, or just eliminate the original?

Comment: @Andy - Yes and keep the TLDR under 100 words.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Ok, it's shorter now.  Was 1000 words, now 400.  I am not sure I can get it to 250, much less only 100 and still hit all the points I feel are relevant.

Comment: @Question3CPO better?

Comment: @Andy Yes, but I'm not a mod so I can't re-open and can't answer if it's closed.

Comment: I faced the same scenario, still the "excessive" (= "non-saving", absolutely no debt...) spender was college me. I solved this way: Money arrives---->Bills are auto-paid----> my "savings target" (20%) gets automatically moved to the savings account -----> My " big yearly expenses" budget goes to "big yearly expenses account" ----> what is left is what I am supposed to live on during the month.  End of.
Obviously this requires a fair bit of planning but works. NOTE: the card that end up in daily use needs to be one that CANNOT go "under". No money, transaction denied. 
Please, re-open.

Comment: @Caterpillaraoz Yeah, unfortunately all my attempts at cutting off the credit card have failed ultimately failed.  I love my wife and am not leaving her, but I feel that would really be the end game if I insisted on that route.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy solution to this. Unfortunately I think you need a different approach, as you say, using software to track expenses to visualise the percentages and such hasn't helped and in my own experience this sort of money management does not work with all people. Maybe you need to look at the expenses and decide what you can cut out. Somehow we all need to make a distinction between what we need (milk, bread) and what we don't need (magazines, dvds) but still purchase every now and then. Sadly buying things for the second category quickly builds up a bill just as big as the one for the weekly shop only that it contains nothing of actual value and it just seems too easy for some to spend and equal amount of money on "wants" as on "needs" and if a substantial amount of your outgoings are in this category that's where you need to focus the discussion. If you can't find any purchases like that I suspect you need to buy less expensive food.

Comment: The problem is, **he knows this and, I'd bet, she knows this** from the sound and wording of the question.  The problem isn't knowledge or what they're spending money on, it's what do they have to lose if they miss their goals?  What does each have to lose if they miss their goals?  Read the question again - he ends up being frustrated (he loses), she loses nothing.  **That's a huge problem**.

Comment: Trust me I understand the problem - I've had it myself. To some (i.e the spouse) , it is not a problem going over the budget all the time as long as they have what they crave because this is their goal.